# Actors in both Star Trek and Doctor Who

Tags: star-trek, doctor-who

I saw a headline today that read "Star Trek actor dies".  Naturally I had to click the link to find out who it was.  It ended up being Olaf Pooley whom I had never heard of.  In reading his Wikipedia page, I learned that he is one of 28 actors to appear in both Star Trek and Doctor Who.  Who are the other 27 actors that have appeared in both franchises?

Comment: The Final Twenty-Seven.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a list of them from [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Doctor_Who#Actors_who_have_appeared_in_both_franchises)!

- [Daphne Ashbrook](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Daphne_Ashbrook):

  - Melora Pazlar (*DS9*: 'Melora')
  - Dr Grace Holloway (Dr Who: The TV Movie)
- [Amy Benedict](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Amy_Benedict):

  - Female Bajoran Villager (*DS9*: 'The Storyteller')
  - Bridget Howe (Torchwood: 'Rendition')
- [Steven Berkoff](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Steven_Berkoff):

  - Hagath (*DS9*: 'Business as Usual')
  - The Shakri (Doctor Who: The Power of Three)
- [Jason Brooks](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Jason_Brooks):

  - Romulan Helmsman (*Star Trek* (2009))
  - Press Secratary (Torchwood: The Middle Men)
- [Noel Clarke](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Noel_Clarke):

  - Thomas Harewood (*Star Trek Into Darkness*)
  - Mickey Smith (Doctor Who: 'Rose' to 'The End of Time Part II')
- [Alan Dale](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Alan_Dale):

  - Praetor Hiren (*Star Trek Nemesis*)
  - Professor Aaron Copley (Torchwood: Reset)
- [John de Lancie](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/John_de_Lancie)

  - Q from *Star Trek*
  - Allen Shapiro (Torchwood: 'End of the Road', 'The Gathering', 'The Blood Line')
- [Van Epperson](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Van_Epperson)

  - Bajoran Clerk (*DS9*: 'Q-Less') & Burlesque Show Alien (*ENT*: 'Broken Bow')
  - CIA Archivist (Torchwood: The New World)
- [John Franklyn-Robbins](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/John_Franklyn-Robbins)

  - Macias (*TNG*: 'Preemptive Strike")
  - Lord Ferain (Doctor Who: Genesis of the Daleks Pt 1)
- [Paul Hayes](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Paul_Hayes)

  - R. Ascher (*ENT*: 'Carbon Creek')
  - Costerdane (Torchwood: Immortal Sins)
- [Sonita Henry](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sonita_Henry)

  - *USS Kelvin* Doctor (*Star Trek* (2009))
  - Meme (Doctor Who: The Time of the Doctor)
- [Bari Hochwald](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Bari_Hochwald)

  - Elizabeteh Lense (*DS9*: 'Explorers'), Brin (*VOY*: 'Friendship One') & E'lis (*ENT*: 'Marauders')
  - ER Nurse (Torchwood: 'Rendition')
- [Barrie Ingham](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Barrie_Ingham)

  - Danilo Odell (*TNG*: 'Up the Long Ladder')
  - Paris Alydon (Doctor Who: The Myth Makers; Small Prophet, Quick Return; Death of a Spy; Horse of Destruction; Doctor Who and the Daleks)
- [George Murdock](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/George_Murdock)

  - 'God' (*Star Trek V*); J.P. Hanson (*TNG*: 'The Best of Both Worlds I & II')
  - Preacher (Torchwood: Dead of Night)
- [Christopher Neame](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Christopher_Neame)

  - Unferth (*VOY*: 'Heroes and Demons') & German General (*ENT*: 'Storm Front Pts I and II')
  - Skagra (Doctor Who: Shada)
- [Simon Pegg](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Simon_Pegg)

  - Montgomery Scott (*Star Trek* (2009) & *Star Trek Into Darkness*)
  - The Editor (Doctor Who: The Long Game)
- [Maurice Roëves](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Maurice_Ro%C3%ABves)

  - Romulan Captain (*TNG*: 'The Chase')
  - Stotz (Doctor Who: The Caves of Androzani Pts I - IV)
- [Deep Roy](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Deep_Roy)

  - Keenser (*Star Trek* (2009) & *Star Trek Into Darkness*)
  - Mr Sin (Doctor Who: The Talons of Weng-Chiang Pts I - VI) & Posicarian Delegate (Doctor Who: The Trial of a Time Lord Pt VII)
- [Robin Sachs](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Robin_Sachs)

  - General Valen (*VOY*: 'The Void')
  - British Professor (Torchwood: The New World)
- [Mark Sheppard](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Mark_Sheppard)

  - Leucon (*VOY*: 'Collective'; 'Child's Play')
  - Canton Delaware (Doctor Who: The Impossible Astronaut; Day of thee Moon)
- [W. Morgan Sheppard](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/W._Morgan_Sheppard)

  - Ira Graves (*TNG*: 'The Schizoid Man'); Klingon Commandant (*Star Trek VI*); Qatai (*VOY*: 'Bliss'); Vulcan Science Minister (*Star Trek* (2009))
  - Old Canton Delaware (Doctor Who: The Impossible Astronaut)
- [Guy Siner](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Guy_Siner)

  - Stuart Reed (*ENT*: 'Silent Enemy')
  - Ravon (Doctor Who: Genesis of the Daleks Pt 1 - III)
- [Eric Steinberg](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Eric_Steinberg)

  - Paul Porter (*Star Trek: First Contact*); Ankari captain (*VOY*: 'Equinox Pt II')
  - Zheng Yibao (Torchwood: The Middle Men)
- [Nana Visitor](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Nana_Visitor)

  - Kira Nerys (*DS9*)
  - Olivia Colasanto (Torchwood: Immortal Sins; End of the Road)
- [David Warner](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/David_Warner)

  - St. John Talbot (*Star Trek V*); Chancellor Gorkon (*Star Trek VI*); Gul Madred (*TNG*: 'Chain of Command Pt I & II')
  - Azlok (voice) (Doctor Who: Dreamland); Prof. Grisenko (Doctor Who: Cold War)
- [Richard Wharton](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Richard_Wharton)

  - Jossen (*ENT*: 'The Seventh')
  - Dr Paul Bell (Torchwood: Rendition)
- [David Youse](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/David_Youse)

  - Nalbis (*ENT*: 'Chosen Realm')
  - Dr Rosenbloom (Torchwood: Dead of Night)
- [Kelvin Yu](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kelvin_Yu)

  - Medical technician (*Star Trek* (2009))
  - Nicolas Frumkin (Torchwood: Escape to LA)

And you of course know about the late [Olaf Pooley](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Olaf_Pooley).

Comment: Interestingly, it looks as though most of these actors appeared in *Torchwood* rather than *Doctor Who* proper

Comment: I completely forgot that Simon Pegg was The Editor.

Comment: @JasonBaker: Given that the fourth season *[Miracle Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torchwood:_Miracle_Day),* which was a British–American co-production, is responsible for 13 entries on this list (all Torchwood entries except Alan Dale), it makes rather sense to me.

Comment: David Warner also played the Doctor in Big Finish's "Unbound" series. He played an alternate Third Doctor in the audio adventures "Sympathy for the Devil" and "Masters of War."